# Javascript class extends child class functionality

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to call parent class function in child class in javascript ES6?

Comment: with `super()` usage.

Comment: `super.<parent method>(<parameters>)`

Answer (score 1):

Call `super()` in the child class constructor to access the parent method in ES6.

```js
class Parent{
  constructor(){}
  sayHello(){ // <--------access this method from Parent class.
     console.log('Hello!');
  }
}

class Child extends Parent{ // <-----extend the Parent class
   constructor(){ 
     super(); // <-----you have to call the "super();" here in constructor
   } 
   alertit(){
      super.sayHello(); // <----now here parent class methods can be accessed here
  }
}

var c = new Child();

c.alertit(); // <----will log Hello!
```

#### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ketehohoye/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly mentioned on the MDN article about [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) keyword.

```
super([arguments]); // calls the parent constructor.
super.functionOnParent([arguments]);
```